# Debian 12.5 kernel fails to install

Tags: debian, kernel, nvidia

Just tried to upgrade to the new Debian Bookworm point release 12.5 But...

```
Building module:
Cleaning build area...
env NV_VERBOSE=1 make -j4 modules KERNEL_UNAME=6.1.0-18-amd64.............................(bad exit status: 2)
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.1.0-18-amd64 (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia-current/525.147.05/build/make.log for more information.
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
dkms: autoinstall for kernel: 6.1.0-18-amd64 failed!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.1.0-18-amd64 (--configure):
 installed linux-image-6.1.0-18-amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up linux-headers-6.1.0-18-amd64 (6.1.76-1) ...
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:
dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.1.0-18-amd64.
Sign command: /usr/lib/linux-kbuild-6.1/scripts/sign-file
Signing key: /var/lib/dkms/mok.key
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/dkms/mok.pub
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Remove NVIDIA drivers, upgrade, install them back. And kernel 6.1.76 requires a patch for NVIDIA drivers: https://github.com/NVIDIA/open-gpu-kernel-modules/issues/594#issuecomment-1925186162

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Thanks! I just timeshifted back and guess I won't be stepping up to this point release.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is a kernel. I looked make.log and found these.

> Module.symvers -e
> 320s ERROR: modpost: GPL-incompatible module nvidia.ko uses GPL-only symbol
> '__rcu_read_unlock'
> 320s ERROR: modpost: GPL-incompatible module nvidia.ko uses GPL-only symbol
> '__rcu_read_lock'
> 320s make[4]: ***
> [/usr/src/linux-headers-6.6.15-common/scripts/Makefile.modpost:145:
> /var/lib/dkms/nvidia-tesla-470/470.223.02/build/Module.symvers] Error 1

I think we need a wait at this patch or other coming Debian https://github.com/gentoo/gentoo/blob/c64caf53/x11-drivers/nvidia-drivers/files/nvidia-drivers-470.223.02-gpl-pfn_valid.patch

Comment: Thanks! I looked at that, but do not know how to incorporate the patch.